# Weird behaviour of AndroidJavaObject in Unity, when implemented through C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

Rather long post follows. It's fairly complex, needs someone who has worked with Unity Plugins before (creating them, not using them) and I'm not looking to get downvoted because a few common search terms show up. So, please read the entire post.

So, I've been having a rather weird issue happening when I try to call native functions through Unity's [AndroidJavaObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.html)

I've built native plugins in the past before, I'm trying to remove my dependancies on having to update multiple JARs each time I need to update my plugins. So, I'm moving a lot of my native Java code from plugins, into Unity itself.

Specifically, there's a way to call native Android functions (i.e. system functions) straight from C#, rather than creating a plugin and calling a function in the plugin that invokes the native function.

For example, earlier, if I had to create a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html), I'd have to write some native code in Java, export the plugin and then call the function. These days, one can just call the [Toast.makeText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) straight  from C# as follows.

Here's how I make the call for a Toast.

```
    public static void Toast (string text, int duration) {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        CreateActivity();

        activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable ( () => {
            new AndroidJavaObject("android.widget.Toast", activity)
                .CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("makeText", activity, text, duration)
                    .Call("show");
        }) );
        #endif
    }
```

and here's the CreateActivity method

```
private static void CreateActivity () {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    if(activity == null)
        activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").
            GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    #endif

}
```

This works perfectly. However, when I try the same approach for creating an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html), I get an ***androidjavaexception java.lang.classnotfoundexception***

Here's the relevant code

```
public static void ShowAlert (string title, string message, string buttonText) {

    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR

    CreateActivity();

    activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable ( () => {
        var builder = new AndroidJavaObject("android.app.AlertDialog.Builder", activity);
        ***//Exception happens in the above line***

        builder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setMessage", message)  
            .Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setTitle", title)
                .Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setCancelable", false)
                .Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setNeutralButton", buttonText)
                .Call("show");
    }) );
    #endif
}
```

What I've tried

1. Used *android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder* instead of *android.app.AlertDialog.Builder*
2. Added the support JARs for v7 & v4 (Specifically *android-support-v4* & *android-support-v7-appcompat*)
3. Tried creating my own implementation for Unity's JNI and invoking that

All the above failed. (The third one, rather spectacularly)

Now, I tried other classes as well, and most of them work (such as [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html), which is a subclass of AlertDialog), and those work!

At this point, I'm rather stumped and I can't think of a VALID reason for certain functions to work, and the others to fail.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

**EDIT 1: Added LogCat**

```
I/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.AlertDialog.Builder
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr clazz, IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._AndroidJavaObject (System.String className, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject..ctor (System.String className, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at AndroidNative+<ShowAlert>c__AnonSto
```

Comment: Interesting issue! Is it the actual android.app.AlertDialog.Builder class that is triggering the ClassNotFoundException (i.e. and not one of the implicit classes used in the applied method calls)? A logcat excerpt might provide useful extra information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are running into, is that AlertDialog.Builder is a *nested class* of AlertDialog, and creating nested classes through reflection (which is what AndroidJavaObject is trying to do) requires a slightly different syntax in Java:

```
android.app.AlertDialog$Builder
```

There are some other tiny mistakes in your code (that you couldn't know about because your constructor wasn't working):

- setNeutralButton requires a callback argument (which can be null)
- show has to be called on the AlertDialog itself, not on the builder.

Taking these tiny corrections into consideration, a working code sample looks like this:

```
public static void ShowAlert(string title, string message, string buttonText)
{
    CreateActivity();

    activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
    {
        var builder = new AndroidJavaObject("android.app.AlertDialog$Builder", activity);

        builder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setMessage", message)
            .Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setTitle", title)
                .Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setCancelable", false)
                .Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setNeutralButton", buttonText, null)
                .Call<AndroidJavaObject>("create")
                .Call("show");
    }));
}
```

Comment: If any of the other classes you couldn't access still can't be instantiated using this approach, please add them to your question (or start a new question) and I'll see if I can figure it out. It's good to get some more documentation out there on the whole Unity-Android interop process!

Comment: Wow. I have no idea how I missed that. It's not the first time I'm working with nested classes, and now I'm laughing at myself going, "Oh how did you miss that?" Yeah, I know there's some inconsistencies on the rest of it that I'd have to fix. I took some code out (the OnClickListeners) for the purpose of this question. Thanks a bunch.